# Blender - Test the area if it's currently in full screen (maximized)

Tags: boolean, toggle, fullscreen, blender

i just want to ask how to test if the area (specifically the 3d view) is maximized or in fullscreen
And is there a boolean syntax for it instead of a toggle, thank tou in advance and cheers!

PS: i didnt include any codes to this simple question

Answer (score 0):

You can test for fullscreen with the boolean `bpy.context.screen.show_fullscreen`. This is a read-only property, you can't set it.